# Xamarin Forms stacklayout fill screen on landscape

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

How can I do stacklayout take all screen width when device is in Landscape?
 [in Landscape mode stacklayout does not fill parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEw8t.png)

here is my Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListView"
         x:Class="ListView.MainPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Silver" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Maroon" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Button Text="Reload data" Clicked="reloadData" x:Name="btnReload"/>
            <ListView x:Name="listView">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Imagen}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="120"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Titulo}" TextColor="Gray"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Fecha}"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator BackgroundColor="Green" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,.2,.2" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Color="Blue"
                            IsRunning="True" IsVisible="False" x:Name="overlay"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I want stacklayout take screen width on landscape; but only on portrait is work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When controls are direct children of an `AbsoluteLayout` setting `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` has no effect. All of the sizing must come from setting `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` and `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags`. So try changing your `StackLayout` to this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Silver"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
               BackgroundColor="Maroon"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    ...
```

Then you also may need to set your `ListView.HorizontalOptions` to `FillAndExpand` but try without that first.

Comment: is working now :) and really clear answer. Thank's so much

Comment: @EricOcampo No problem at all. Glad it worked for you.